# JS: revealing module pattern - accessing internal objects vs arrays?

Tags: javascript, scope, private-members, revealing-module-pattern

Using the revealing module pattern, how can I provide *direct* access to non-static private variables? Here's what I have:

```
var M = function () {
    var obj = {};
    var arr = [];
    var change = function () {
        obj = {"key":"if I see this, O is a reference to obj"};
        arr.push("If I see this, A is a reference to arr")
        };
    return {
        change: change,
        O: obj,
        A: arr
        };
}();

M.change();
console.log(M.A); // prints ["If I see this, A is a reference to arr"] 
console.log(M.O); // prints Object {}, wanted "if I see this, O..."
```

It seems that A references arr directly, while O settles for a copy of obj's value at initialization time. I would understand the behavior if obj were a string, float, or boolean.

I could of course expose obj via a public get_obj method, but I'm still curious if this can be solved without additional help methods (I want to keep the *interface* to obj intact). Furthermore, what's so special about arrays that objects don't have, that causes this behavior?

Really grateful for any insights,

Comment: In `change`, you're re-setting value of the `obj` variable, but modifying the `arr` variable in place. `M.A` and `M.O` are references to the values that `arr` and `obj` held at that point. Changing the value of the `obj` and `arr` variables doesn't affect `M`. There's no copying done. Maybe you meant to do `obj.key = "if I see this...";`. If you want to reset the whole `obj` and only have one key/value pair in it, you can loop through it and `delete` properties, then use `.key = "if I see this..."`

Comment: Ah, I see, and changing O.key did the trick. In my original code I had 'O = d3.layout.force()' which is quite a complex object... =/

Answer (score 1):

```
obj["key"] = "if I see this, O is a reference to obj";
```

You can set the `key` property for `obj` and keep the reference to the original object.